# Recursive least squares filter for vector input

Tags: filtering, signal-processing

All the online tutorials, articles and book chapters that I could find on Recursive Least Squares (RLS) filter assume that the input signal is a scalar (one dimensional). Vectors and matrices do appear in the formalism but they are due to the FIR filter's order i.e. input is transformed from a scalar to the (p+1)-vector of historical/delayed samples (where p is the filter order).

Any pointers on how to extend the formalism to vector inputs would be greatly appreciated.